# Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed - Error: Already seen Doctype

Tags: android, gradle, refresh, doctype

I'm going mad! I've already searched and tried everything (google and stackoverflow) but nothing seems to help.

I'm trying to open (tried also to import) a slidenerd project on Github (http://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest) to Android Studio 1.2.1.1 with Gradle 2.2, but what I got is this annoying error!

> Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed
>
> Error: Already seen Doctype

Can you help me to understand what can I do to solve?

This is my Gradle console log:

Executing tasks: [:]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.0.1/lint-24.0.1.pom

[Fatal Error] lint-24.0.1.pom:3:10: Doctype già presente (means Already seen).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'MehdiApp'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        :MehdiApp:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1
  >   Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.0.1/lint-24.0.1.pom
  >   Doctype già presente.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.331 secs

Answer (score 7):

It happened to me when I had two google repositories and `gradle:3.0.0` as dependencies  in `build.gradle` file :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

That was an obvious mistake. So I removed `maven` part and changed `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

network might be the reason.
i changed my vpn network then `gradle` build was successful.

Comment: Had the exact same problem and changing the VPN port did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

None of the above solutions worked for me. For me the fix was changing the gradle home (.gradle) to a new location

Comment: You should comment in the answer that it does not work.